# Using namespaces with the Datastore or Using namespaces with the Memcache

Tags: python, google-app-engine, namespaces, memcached

i am really finding these options confusing in the documentation, would memcache use ancestor queries? Can I use both and how would that work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, Memcache doesn't use ancestor queries, nor even 'queries' per se.  Whilst Memcache and Datastore are both essentially key-value stores, Datastore supports queries (using indexes) and transactions.  Datastore is for your persistent data storage.

Memcache on the other hand simply provides *put* and *get* actions, with high performance, but with no guarantees on your objects' availability.  (Memcache also provides atomic counters and *put-if-untouched* capabilities). Because it's a cache, your data may be evicted at any time.  As such, you should think of memcache as being a way to improve the performance or efficiency of your application.

Also, namespaces and ancestor queries are unrelated.  A namespace is simply a way to help you partition your data (perhaps for a multi-tenanted application). Both Datastore and Memcache support namespaces.

An ancestor path defines the scope of your consistency - either in an **ancestor query** or a **transaction**.  To understand the purpose of ancestors, you should read up on the concept of [Entity Groups](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/entities).

Comment: I have been using ndb and not db, I am starting to wonder if it was such a good idea

Comment: Was a help thanks, I get very confused using both db and ndb but the link was useful

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what are you asking about "ancestor queries" but as for namespaces, in Python both datastore and memcache APIs are using namespace_manager#get_namespace for lookups/puts/... though in the memcache API you can override it by explicitly passing a namespace in the requests (see: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/memcache/clientclass)